# Actionscript 3 Package Trouble

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, package

My code is:

```
package com.companyName.softwareName {

    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class SoftwareName extends Sprite {

        public function SoftwareName() {

            trace("Testing!");

        }

}
```

and it is located in C:/dev/com/companyName/SoftwareName as SoftwareName.as

Taking the package name out lets it compile, but when it is in it tells me it the package structure isn't right, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Is it an error I made? Or possibly my version of mxmlc is corrupt? I compile it with

```
mxmlc SoftwareName.as
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, what I should have been doing was including "-source-path=C:\dev\" in my compiling script.

Answer (score 0):

> I compile it with `mxmlc SoftwareName.as`

It looks like you're compiling it from the `softwareName` folder. You've to do it from the root of the package structure - the `c:\dev\` folder. The compiler expects `pack.pack1.SomeClass` to be in `pack/pack1/` folder relative to the current folder (from where the compiler was triggered).

```
cd \dev
mxmlc com\companyName\softwareName\SoftwareName.as
```